# Are benchmarking and post-stratification equivalent?

Tags: terminology, post-hoc

Does "benchmarking" and "post-stratification" describe exactly the same process? The Wikipedia article on [Statistical Benchmarking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_benchmarking) claims it is; however, the article on [Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28statistics%29) also mentions "poststratification" but doesn't link to "benchmarking".

Perhaps there are other applications of benchmarking besides post-stratification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Benchmarking" is not a term I am familiar with in this context but the description in Wikipedia of benchmarking is indeed the same as what I regard to be post-stratification.  I suspect "benchmarking" is a minority term in the survey sample field but am prepared to be corrected.

Most google searches for "statistical benchmarking" come up with something completely different ie the more everyday use of benchmarking as a standard or reference point against which to compare various cases.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the term "benchmarking" in a Time Series context, and one definition I've seen for that is:

> Benchmarking refers to techniques used to ensure coherence between
>   time series data of the same target variable measured at different
>   frequencies, for example, sub-annually and annually.  Benchmarking
>   consists of imposing the level of the benchmark series while
>   minimizing the revisions of the observed movement in the sub-annual
>   series as much as possible. Consequently, the growth rates in the
>   benchmarked series are coherent with those from the benchmarks. In
>   certain situations, benchmarking can improve the accuracy and
>   timeliness of statistical output.

Not sure if that's applicable in one of these two definitions or not.